# Can you enumerate all values of an inductive type in Coq?

Tags: types, coq, induction

Is there a way to enumerate the values of a finite inductive type in Coq?

E.g., consider the type:

```
Inductive state := A | B | C | D | E.
```

Is there any way to take this definition and from it, programmatically gain access to `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`? I know in a proof I can use the `induction` tactic to prove for each case, but I want to be able to loop over the values of the type.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "enumerate".  In the Mathematical Components libraries, there is a `finType` interface for types with finitely many elements (https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.fintype.html).  If `T : finType`, the term `enum T` collects all elements of `T` in a list.

It used to be the case that you had to build instances of this interface by hand. Since this process is tedious, I built a [library](https://github.com/arthuraa/deriving) for automating it. Maybe the library is overkill for your needs, but there is some code for inferring all the constructors of a type based on its induction principle. If you are interested in this, I can explain how it works in more detail.

I have also heard that the Ltac2 tactic language allows you to access the list of constructors of an inductive type, but I don't know how this works...